# Synchronizing database from multiple locations to a central database and vice versa

Tags: mysql, synchronization

I have several databases server located in different locations and a central database which is in a data center. All have the same schema. All of them are changed(insert/update/delete) in each location with different data including the central database.

I would like to synchronise(manully at midnight using some scripts) all the data in the central database. I would also like all data in the central database synchronise to all locations. What I mean is that database change in location 1 should also be reflected in location 2 database.

Any ideas on how to go about this using the procedure scripts ?

Thanks in Advance

Michael SopRaj

Answer (score 0):

Try [Data Comparison tool](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/database-synchronization.html) in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). We also have stand-alone tool - [dbForge Data Compare](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/datacompare/).

Command line is supported.